# How to force my virtualenv to see this compiled module installed at the system level?

Tags: python, import, gconf

I installed the package *python-gconf* on Ubuntu 12.04 and played with it: it's a python binding to the gnome configuration tool, and there is no pypi package for it.

As soon as I created a virtualenv (**without** `--no-site-packages`), any attempt to import `gconf` would lead to `ImportError`.

The `gconf` module works fine at the system level, but not in the virtual env. I investigated, and opening *python-gconf.deb* teached me that it's just a gconf.so binary.

Searching for it tells me it's been installed in */home/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gconf.so*

I did try to force Python hands:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gconf.so ~/.virtualenvs/appetizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

But it only resulted in:

```
>>> import gconf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: could not import gobject (error was: 'No module named gobject')
```

So I'm guessing it's very dependant to GTK.

Comment: does your version of virtualenv have `--system-site-packages`. `--no-site-packages` is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks J.F. That was the problem. You should write it as an answer so I can upvote you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create your virtualenv using `--system-site-packages` option to make all system packages visible. Symlinking external packages into virtualenv's structure also works for most situations when you need only one external package.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created your virtual environment, just remove the `no-global-site-packages.txt` file from it to make it see system packages.